# Запретить от индексации в роботс только некоторые страницы

Tags: robots.txt

Доброго времени. 
Есть страницы

```
сайт.ру/advert/rossia/

сайт.ру/advert/rossia/moskva/
сайт.ру/advert/rossia/rostov/ и т.д по городам

сайт.ру/advert/rossia/moskva/resultl23.html
сайт.ру/advert/rossia/rostov/resultl23434.html и т.д
```

Как запретить именно страницы с гео и можно ли, чтобы не писать вручную?
Т.е страницы

```
 сайт.ру/advert/ и сайт.ру/advert/rossia/moskva/resultl23.html
```

должны быть открыты для индексации

Спасибо.

Comment: Я правильно понял? От индексации должны быть закрыты страницы: `/advert/rossia/*`, кроме `/advert/rossia/moskva/*`?

Comment: `/advert/rossia/moskva/ - закрыта

/advert/rossia/moskva/категория/ - закрыта

/advert/-открыта
/advert/категория/-открыта`

Comment: с учетом вашего комментария исправил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Disallow: /advert/rossia/*
```

[Инструкция на Яндексе](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml?lang=ru)